# How does SQL Server handles Spaces in Substring/LEFT?

Tags: sql-server, string

How does SQL Server handles Spaces in Substring/LEFT?

If there's a SPACE where at the Substring/Left cutoff, I get a different value than if there's text.
Is there documentation for this?

```
DECLARE @st_Spaces char(25)
DECLARE @st_NoSpaces char(25)

SET @st_Spaces = '123 56'  --One space, pos 4
SET @st_NoSpaces = REPLACE(@st_Spaces, ' ', '4') --Replace space w/ 4


SELECT LEN(LEFT(@st_Spaces, 4)), --Returns 3
LEN(LEFT(@st_NoSpaces,4)) --Returns 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right there in the documentation for [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx).

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   **excluding trailing blanks**. (emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

`LEN()` excludes trailing blanks, which is where you are getting the differing length values.

Answer (score 0):

`LEN(...)` does not count trailing whitespace. You can verify this by doing:

```
SELECT LEN('    '); -- returns 0
SELECT LEN('A   '); -- returns 1
SELECT LEN('  A '); -- returns 3
```